# Text color change in the table

Tags: php, html, css

```
<td style='color:blue;'><?php echo $row['birthday'];?></td>
```

I want to change the color of the text in a td element in html.

It works while loading the page, but after the page is loaded the style does not work.

How can I get it working?

Comment: What does your `$row['birthday']` look like? If it's a date (I assume), what is its format?

Comment: @AnisR I edited my question.

Comment: `if(condition ==x){} else{}` is the basic method. You can insert almost anything you want in there in order to make something do something.

Comment: Consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your work on what you are stuck with with CODE example.

Comment: @ewef Changing the question will not help. Its the same thing you are asking. which  FunkFortyNiner have already commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would encapsulate the logic that decides which css class to apply to the  element based on the birthday inside a function *makeTdClass*:

```
function makeTdClass($date) {
    /* compare $date with current date and return "red", "blue" or "" */
}
```

With such a function, you would pass in the date parameter and it would return the appropiated css class, wich you might define on a  tag on in a separated .css file:

```
red {
    color: red;
}
blue {
    color: blue;
}
```

Finally, you would be able to call this function from within your PHP file and put the returned value as the class attribute of your  elements:

```
<?php $tdClass = makeTdClass($row['birthday']); ?>
<td class="<?php echo $tdClass;?>"><?php echo $row['birthday'];?></td>
```

You can use the short way for inserting php content:

```
<td class="<?= makeTdClass($row['birthday']) ?>"><?= $row['birthday'] ?></td>
```

Comment: why can't I use ```style``` in td and need to use a function?

Comment: @ewef Of course you can adapt this code by using the style attribute there. I prefer to use the class atribute because you can encapsulate in the css class the different style configurations according to the different ways you want to render the <td> element. Let's say you also want to increment the font size whenever the text is red, then you would add "font-size: 25px;" to your red class. By using the style way, you would need to change the style calculation adding a font-size statement. Now think in adding more and more different behaviours using this way.